# USB Type C Y-cable or KVM Switch to connect two sources to a HUB

Tags: usb, switch, kvm, cable

I have got a display with an integrated USB type C hub. The keyboard and mouse are plugged into the monitor and the display is interconnected via USB type C to provide video signal, power and the USB connection itself of course.

Currently, I have a MacBook Pro attached to it. I want to add a mini-PC to the setup. It does the same thing. The USB cord gets plugged into it and the keyboard, mouse and display are connected.

However, I want to "hide" the mini-PC in my desk and that's why it's not very practical that I need to unplug the USB c cable every time I want to use the other PC.

Is there some sort of Y cable or KVM switch device so that I can leave both computers plugged in simultaneously? Preferably with a switch so that even both of them can run while I only need to change the source with a simple "press".

Note: the cable has USB type C on both ends.

[image]

Comment: The cable connecting to the computers and display has a USB-C connector on both ends, correct?

Comment: @Cfinley Yes :)

Comment: What you are looking for is traditionally described not as a "Y-cable" (which would be a non-spec-conformant and dangerous device, in this case) but a "KVM switch". (Unfortunately I don't have any recommendations about switches for USB Type C, but perhaps adjusting the terminology in your question will help you get an answer.)